# String array : Adding elements in Loop

Tags: java, loops, arrays

Here is my code

```
LDAPAttributeSet attributeSet = new LDAPAttributeSet();

String rolesName;
String uniquemem[] = rolesName.split(",");

if (uniquemem.length == 1)
    attributeSet.add(new LDAPAttribute("uniqueMember",
                        new String[] { "cn="+uniquemem[0]}));

if (uniquemem.length == 2)
    attributeSet.add(new LDAPAttribute("uniqueMember",
                        new String[] {
                                "cn=" +uniquemem[0],   
                                "cn=" + uniquemem[1]
                                    }));
if (uniquemem.length == 3)
    attributeSet.add(new LDAPAttribute("uniqueMember",
                        new String[] {
                                "cn=" + uniquemem[0]
                                        ,
                                "cn=" + uniquemem[1]
                                         ,
                                "cn=" + uniquemem[2]
                                          }));
```

I have tried by using `List<String>` and `StringBuffer` in forloop to add/append content dynamically but it is accepting only String[].
Please help me solve this issue

I have tried this

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer()
            for(int i=0;i<uniquemem.length;i++)
            {
                sb.append("cn=" + uniquemem[i]);
            }

attributeSet.add(new LDAPAttribute("uniqueMember",sb.toString()));
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What doesn't work here?

Comment: `attributeSet` is not defined...

Comment: @Mureinik I want to add element in String[] dynamically based on the length of uniquemem[]

Comment: What is the issue with your code ? BTW it miss a "," in the condition `if (uniquemem.length == 2)`after `"cn=" +uniquemem[0]`

Comment: Any error messages ? Your code looks good to me

Comment: @daguru sorry for typo mistake, i want to generate a dynamic string without using if conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this..

```
LDAPAttributeSet attributeSet = new LDAPAttributeSet();

String rolesName;
String uniquemem[] = rolesName.split(",");

String item = null;
String arrayItems[uniquemem.length]

for(int i=0; i<uniquemem.length; i++) {
    item = "cn=" + uniquemem[i];
    arrayItems[i] = item;
}


attributeSet.add(new LDAPAttribute("uniqueMember", arrayItems);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the String array you need:

```
ArrayList<String> memList = new ArrayList<>(uniquemem.length);
for(int i = 0; i < uniquemem.length; i++) {
    memList.add("cn=" + uniquemem[i]);
}
memList.trimToSize();
memList.toArray(String[0]);
String[] memArray = memList.toArray(new String[memList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the existing `uniqemem` array like this

```
for(int i=0;i<uniquemem.length;i++)
{
    uniquemem[i] = "cn=" + uniquemem[i];
}
attributeSet.add(new LDAPAttribute("uniqueMember", uniquemem));
```